# Excel VBA to Deal With AJAX

Tags: ajax, excel, vba

I am practicing to use excel vba to download information from website: http://mops.twse.com.tw/mops/web/t05sr01_1

But I have no idea how to download the data behind click button, as the image shown: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KZHiZ.jpg

I excerpt its web code as below. Could anyone explain me how to code in excel vba to get its data?

Thank you very mush.

Web code:

```
<td style='text-align:left !important;' nowrap>鴻海</td>
<td style='text-align:left !important;'>105/01/05</td>
<td style='text-align:left !important;'>11:41:00</td>
<td style='text-align:left !important;'>說明媒體報導</td>
<td><input type='button' value='詳細資料' onclick="document.fm_t05sr01_1.SEQ_NO.value='1';document.fm_t05sr01_1.SPOKE_TIME.value='114100';document.fm_t05sr01_1.SPOKE_DATE.value='20160105';document.fm_t05sr01_1.COMPANY_NAME.value='?E??';document.fm_t05sr01_1.COMPANY_ID.value='2317';document.fm_t05sr01_1.skey.value='2317201601051';document.fm_t05sr01_1.hhc_co_name.value='?E??';ajax1(this.form,'table01');">
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't shown how you are getting the html.

You can use a CSS selector.

General for first input button

```
input[type=button]
```

This says element(s) with `input` tag having attribute `type` whole value is `'button'`

You apply with the querySelector method, or querySelectorAll if more than one match and then use index for required element.

```
ie.document.querySelector("input[type=button]").Click
```

If in an HTMLDocument variable e.g. `htmlDoc` then

```
htmlDoc.querySelector("input[type=button]").Click
```